# Oracle Apex Master-Detail forms

Tags: oracle, apex, master-detail

How can I create a structure like the picture below?

[The build I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQmAE.png)

Billing information is kept in my master table. items in my detail table too. I show the information in the Items table with the grid. But I don't want to make entries from grid.

I want the information to be added from the window that opens when the "Add Pruduct" button is clicked.

After all the information entries are completed, I want to save the data in the master and detail table by clicking the SAVE ALL button.

additional notes:
Imagine that you are preparing an invoice screen.

I do not want the products in the invoice to be entered on the grid.
There will be a button to add product.

Clicking it will open a new form window.

When we enter the product information in this form and click add, it will be added to the invoice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dialog Form Page can save de data into a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531) (in memory) and then when you "save all" the process must save the master data and then collection data into de detail table.